# how i compress Titanium Application Size after Build in device?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new mobile application developer with Titanium. I build a Log IN Application in which i have 3 window

> 1. Log In Window
> 2. Registration Window
> 3. After Log in Details Show about User in this application one Database, whose store Data about user, It is multiplatform. It is run on both Application (iphone or android)

But, when i install in device than it take `12MB` or more Size (application size `12MB` or more size). how i compress it? Plz, Help me if any knowledge? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to do it:

1. Choose Rhino as a development system instead of v8
2. Go back to SDK 1.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Titanium includes all the possibly libraries in its final binding.But even then it gets the builds as 7.5 - 9  MB after that you code decide a head.
But in your case its more then the expectation.
Do you use any framework in your project ?
Else if you use unnecessary resource like Images in you project.